# How to change the icon for programs in Ubuntu's Applications menu?

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, icons

I downloaded the latest Eclipse but it doesn't provide an installer (it runs off the unzipped file).

I added a shortcut in the Applications menu to it but the icon is the Ubuntu default icon. How can I change it to another icon?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but for anyone else with this problem, try installing it through the Ubuntu Software centre via http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/eclipse/

This should install the package and add all links and icons automatically

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the eclipse icon: Google for eclipse icon and download it, extract it, you will need the .svg file (-icon)
2. right-click applications to go to the menu editor, find your eclipse application, select it and open properties, click on the (wrong-) icon button, select the path to the eclipse.svg file